# Database design

Tags: database-design, mysql-5.5

I have tables college and department.

In `college`, I have serial-number and college-names,

In `department`, i have nos, college-names and department-name.

My challenge is that having a repeated college-name in table department because it is many-to-one relationship, how would I classify the id?

Comment: Please post the tables definitions

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of having a College table would be to use the serial-number as a foreign key in the Department table.

For example, you would have the following tables:

```
College: ID, CollegeName
Department: ID, DeptName, CollegeID
```

(where CollegeID is referenced to ID in College table)

This way, the College name is only listed in the College table and the ID numbers are the references between the tables.

You should consider setting it up with another table between the College and Department tables...

```
College: ID, CollegeName
CollegeDept: CollegeID, DeptID
Department: ID, DeptName
```

This way, the College and Department tables only store the relevant data once and the CollegeDept table is the reference between the 2

Comment: I don't understand the logic of the 2nd design. How can a department be related to 2 (or more) colleges?